# For loop only prints one DIV tag. Not 8 DIV tags

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to loop an array and print the result like this:

```
<div class="photo-palette">
    <div class="photo-palette-inner" style="background-color: rgb(68, 73, 68);"></div>
    <div class="photo-palette-inner" style="background-color: rgb(54, 37, 28);"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var image = $("#histogram-image")[0];
var palette = colorThief.getPalette(image);

for (var i = 0, len = palette.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.photo-palette').html('<div class="photo-palette-inner" style="background-color: rgb(' + palette[i] + ');"></div>');
}
```

But that loop only prints this:

```
<div class="photo-palette">
    <div class="photo-palette-inner" style="background-color: rgb(68, 73, 68);"></div>
</div>
```

I can't see any wrong with this loop! `console.log(palette)` prints the following:

```
[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
    0: Array[3]
        0: 68
        1: 73
        2: 68
        length: 3
        __proto__: Array[0]
    1: Array[3]
    2: Array[3]
    3: Array[3]
    4: Array[3]
    5: Array[3]
    6: Array[3]
    7: Array[3]
    8: Array[3]
    length: 9
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

Can you see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` writes over the entire content of that DIV. You need to `append` in the loop or else your last iteration will be the only content of that div.

Comment: So it was `append()` I should use! Many thanks :D I'll accept your answer as soon as I can